# jQuery change() fires on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code fires on the page load, but not when the change event actually occurs.

```
jQuery('select#order_note_type').change(function() {
  //random code here
});
```

I have to add that it is not inside the `ready` method. Do I need to bind it?

**EDIT**: I changed my code to be inside the `$(document).ready()` and used bind, but I still get my method to fire only at page load:

```
jQuery(document).ready(onReady);

function onReady() {
  jQuery('select#order_note_type').bind('change',showTrackingInfo);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle with this behavior?

Comment: Have you tried placing it inside a `ready` method?

Comment: Binding it won't make a difference. Are you modifying the element or programatically selecting an option when the page loads?

Comment: *This code fires on the page load*: That means you are executing it on page load... are you sure you are passing a function reference and not calling the function instead?

Comment: I tried to put it inside the `$(document).ready()`, but it still fires on the page load.

Comment: Could you provide the surrounding circumstances of the code block? I think this may not be a problem of the code itself you provided. Try reproducing the problem on jsfiddle.net for demonstration; you may find the bug yourself while doing that.

Comment: jQuery change() ... "This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements." ... are you using one of these elements?

Comment: I changed my code and placed it in the OP.

Comment: If you have an ID, only use that in the selector.  Adding the element name slows down your jQuery call.  `jQuery('select#order_note_type')` => `jQuery('#order_note_type')`.  This shouldn't solve your problem, however.

Comment: Works fine with the code you provide here: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/3U2Ua/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('select#order_note_type').bind('change',showTrackingInfo); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case it was because I was firing some events on the controls after the code for the change event. So I suggest you try and move this change event to the end of your script, and also include this script last in the page.